# Different views in one

Tags: php, view, lithium

I´m working on a project using lithium framework and I need to be able to have different views in a "MAIN" view.

For example. I have to be able to see the post and events forms (add a new event and a new post) in the principal view.

I actually have the view for add a new post and a new event. I´m looking the way to include this views in the main one.

Any idea of how to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$this->_render()` is used within the views to include elements. Any variables passed from the controller to the parent view are also available in the element. The third argument of `$this->_render()` can be used to pass additional variables.

```
<?php

// renders app/views/elements/nav.html.php
echo $this->_render('element', 'nav');

?>
```

Relative pathing works, so if you want to reuse a template from say `app/views/events/add.html.php`, you can do this:

```
<?=$this->_render('element', '../events/add'); ?>
```

Comment: I tried to use them and it show the info as I want. The problem is that when I want to store it,  nothing happen. I supose it was because the method to store it is in another controller. I know i can copy/paste the method to this new controller but i think is not the best way to solve this. Any idea? Thanks for ur time!